# Trouble understanding open sets in product topology.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I have the following doubt. Consider a manifold $(M,\tau)$ and its product topology $\tau^2$.

How is then an open set $U\in\tau^2$ defined?

Is it $U=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i\times V_i$, where $U_i,V_i\in\tau$ or $U=\bigcup_{i,j\in I}U_i\times V_j$?

It seems to me that it is the first one because in the second one

\begin{align}
U=\bigcup_{i,j\in I}U_i\times V_j=\bigcup_{i\in I}(\bigcup_{j\in I}U_i\times V_j)=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\times(\bigcup_{j\in I}V_j)=(\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i)\times\text{Im }U=\text{Dom }U\times\text{Im }U
\end{align}

And, so, for example, $U=A\times B\cup C\times D$ could not be an open set if $A$ and $C$, and $B$ and $D$ are disjoint open sets in $\tau$.

Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't follow your reasoning with the equalities, but it should be the second one.  Think for example of what open sets look like in the plane $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.  They are unions of little open boxes $(a,b) \times (c,d)$.

Comment: Note that both sets are open. Every open set in $\tau^2$ has the first form, but not nessecarily the second. An example is $(0,1)\times (0,1) \cup (2,3) \times (2,3) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the first.  An open set is a union of products of open sets, so it would take the form $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \times V_i$.  It is a union of single terms (the terms just happen to have two factors) so only one index is needed.  The second option you present is ``too big."

You should think of an open set as $\bigcup_i \mathcal{O_i}$, where each $\mathcal{O}_i$ has the form $\mathcal{O}_i = U_i \times V_i$.  This makes it clear that one index suffices.